# Can you help me identify this part?

Tags: part-identification, technic

After a lot of circus and calisthenics with a magnifying glass and lamp, I'm still unable to read the part number. I've also clicked thru' about 180 pages of LEGO 'Pick a Brick' and didn't find it there.

Could someone please help me identify this part number? Apologies in advance for my failing eyesight :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is part [11458 Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole on Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11458&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Pin%20Hole%20on%20Top&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). Much easier to find on Bricklink than by scrolling through Pick-a-Brick. Welcome to Bricks.SE!

[image]

Comment: You did me a solid. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

That is a cable guide. you attach it to your house when you want to string your telephone or internet cable from the low-hanging utility wires. It provided tautness for the cable. I mean, not real tautness but enough so the cables don't hang.

Comment: Cable guide?? Wrong. If it was a cable guide you would be able to open the hole to attach the wire otherwise it wouldn't fit due to the plug. [This site is about Lego.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego)

Comment: You can, definitely, use this piece as you have described, but this isn't its primary use. Especially, within other LEGO items.